# Inteligent subtraction of values in array (php)

Tags: arrays, subtraction

PHP Language

Is it difficult to write a function to subtraction value from each [Amount] values in array ?, all that until subtraction value is appeased ?.

Example what i need (before subtraction):

```
[MainStockAddedArr] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [Amount] => 10
                                    [Price] => 19.44
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [Amount] => 15
                                    [Price] => 15.55
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [Amount] => 20
                                    [Price] => 11.55
                                )

                            [3] => Array
                                (
                                    [Amount] => 30
                                    [Price] => 11.10
                                )

                        )
```

Value to subtraction is for example 30 pieces. So i would need to have results in array look like this:

```
    [MainStockAddedArr] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [Amount] => 0
                                    [Price] => 19.44
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [Amount] => 0
                                    [Price] => 15.55
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [Amount] => 15
                                    [Price] => 11.55
                                )

                            [3] => Array
                                (
                                    [Amount] => 30
                                    [Price] => 11.10
                                )

                        )
```

In above example, two values are changed to 0 so that gives 25 pieces already been taken, on third value only 5 has been taken, that gives 30 pieces so no more is needed. This is just example, subtraction value will be dynamic, from a loop which is above this one.

In situation where subtraction value would be greater than in whole array (sum [Amounts]), else is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the sample of FIFO (first in first out) method.. you can try, either make some correction if needed.

As a regular function:

```
function fifo($argArray, $argValue, $colName = 'amount') {

    // initialize
    $total = is_numeric($argValue) ? $argValue : 0;
    $i = 0;

    // check for input amount (total)
    if ($total > 0) {

        // process the input array 
        foreach ($arrArray as $key => $v) {

            // initialize amount value
            $amount = $remains = $v[$colName] ?: 0;

            // check for amount availability
            if ($amount) {
                // increment counter
                $i++;

                // calculate amount value remains
                $remains -= $amount > $total ? $total : $amount;

                // set amount value remains in array
                $argArray[$key][$colName] = $remains;

                // calculate last total remains
                $total -= $amount - $remains;

                // when total remains is zero then exit the loop process
                if ($total === 0) break;
            }
        }
    }

    // return count of rows been used and total remains
    return ['rowsCount' => $i, 'totalRemains' => $total];
}
```

Usage:

```
$result = fifo(<argArray>, <argValue>, [<columnName>]);
```

As a class:

```
namespace AnyNamespace;

class AnyClass extend \ArrayObject {

public function getFifo($argValue, $colName = 'amount') {
    return $this::fifo($this, $argValue, $colName);
}

public static function fifo($argArray, $argValue, $colName = 'amount') {

    // initialize
    $total = is_numeric($argValue) ? $argValue : 0;
    $i = 0;

    // check for input amount (total)
    if ($total > 0) {

        // process the input array 
        foreach ($arrArray as $key => $v) {

            // initialize amount value
            $amount = $remains = $v[$colName] ?: 0;

            // check for amount availability
            if ($amount) {
                // increment counter
                $i++;

                // calculate amount value remains
                $remains -= $amount > $total ? $total : $amount;

                // set amount value remains in array
                $argArray[$key][$colName] = $remains;

                // calculate last total remains
                $total -= $amount - $remains;

                // when total remains is zero then exit the loop process
                if ($total === 0) break;
            }
        }
    }

    // return count of rows been used and total remains
    return ['rowsCount' => $i, 'totalRemains' => $total];
}
}
```

Usage:

```
use AnyNamespace;
...
$result = AnyClass::fifo(<argArray>, <argValue>, [<columnName>]);
```

Or

```
use AnyNamespace;
...
$anyClass = new AnyClass(<inputArray>);

$result = $anyClass->getFifo(<argValue>, [<columnName>]);
```

Comment: I am having array with key numbers which is not in sequence, i mean key 0, key 5, key 12 ect. in such situation function does not subtraction, it does first key subtraction but next ones are intact. Is it possible to modify function so it would not pay attention to the key number but just one after the other order type.